# Table contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

This is my first table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[County] 
(
    [CountyId] INT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [County]   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_County] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CountyId] ASC)
);
```

This is my second table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Theatre] 
(
    [TheatreId]   INT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TheatreName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [CountyId]    INT         NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Theatre] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TheatreId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Theatre_County] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([CountyId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[County] ([CountyId])
);
```

This is my third table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Movies] 
(
    [CinemaId]    INT         NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId]  INT         NOT NULL IDENTITY(101, 1),
    [CinemaName]  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [TheatreId]   INT         NOT NULL,
    [ShowTimings] TIME (7)    NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Movies] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CinemaId], [CategoryId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Movies_Theatre] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([TheatreId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Theatre] ([TheatreId])
);
```

This is my last table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reviews]
(
    [MovieId]          INT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]             VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Genres]           VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Image]            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [ShortDescription] TEXT        NOT NULL,
    [Rating]           VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Grade]            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId]       INT         NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Reviews] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MovieId] ASC), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Reviews_Movies] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryId]) REFERENCES [Movies]([CategoryId]),   
);
```

I have created a relationship between the tables yet I am getting an error while I am updating the last table:

> SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[Movies]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted.

Can any about please tell me what is my mistake that I am doing?

Comment: `ntext` and `text` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: The way you've set this up, you can have **at most ONE review** per movie - since you're using `MovieId` as the primary key for the `Review` table - is that what you want??

Comment: And also you will have no control over the movie that the review is associated with as that is an identity so will be system generated usually

Comment: @Martin Smith- Yes,I am using a composite primary key because the second key which is MovieId is being used in a relationship with other tables and I have keep CategoryId as identity as It is used in relationship with Reviews Table.

Comment: @Martin Smith- Do you think using composite primary key is the issue in the case?

Comment: @marc_s- Yes it is correct I have one review per movie

Comment: @MartinSmith- Now, I have changed the Identity of the Movies table from CategoryId to MovieId still I am getting the same error, What would my mistake possibly be?

Answer (score 1):

Just like the error says, Movies.CategoryId is not a key, so you can't reference it in a Foreign Key.  You need a Categories table that has CategoryId as its primary key.  Then both Reviews and Movies can have a Foreign Key referencing Categories.

Comment: Browne-CategoryId is set as Primary Key in the Movies Table

Comment: @HarshDesai No it is not. The primary key of Movies is a composite key of the **TWO** columns <CinemaId, CategoryId>. To create a foreign key, you must refer to the complete primary key (or unique constraint) of the other table.